# Unable to build a W10 UWP app in "Release" when referenced more than one API-Extension

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

In my Windows 10 Universal app I referenced `Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP` as well as `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP`. Everything works well and compiles in "Debug", but the error below appears when trying to compile in "Release". When referenced only one Extension, the app also compiles in "Release".

> Fehler        Der Befehl ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\ilc.exe"
>   /in:"C:\Users\myName\PROJECTS\myApp\myApp\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in"
>   /out:"C:\Users\myName\PROJECTS\myApp\myApp\bin\x86\Release\ilc"
>   /intermediatespath:"C:\Users\myName\PROJECTS\myApp\myApp\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate"
>   /v:normal /keepintermediates:true /buildtype:ret /exename:"myApp.exe"
>   /makepripath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\bin\x64\MakePri.exe"
>   /appPriProjectRoot:"C:\Users\myName\PROJECTS\myApp\myApp"
>   /rcpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\rc.exe"
>   /targetplatformsdklibpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um"
>   /targetplatformsdkmetadatapath:"C:\Users\myName\PROJECTS\myApp\myApp\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata"
>   /targetframeworkpath:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.MediaControlContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Phone.PhoneContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /externalReferencePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\References\Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract\1.0.0.0"
>   /RdXmlPath:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\LibraryXML"
>   /suppressPDBWarnings:true /AllowNoManagedCode /UseCustomFramework
>   "/logger:CsvLogger;4288;2796"" wurde mit dem Code 1004 beendet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that current Win10 SDK 10240 have some issues about release - it means .NET Native enabled - build.

This link may help you. In my cases, I've succeeded to make release build with updated .target file.

[RTM Known Issue: Release configuration fails to build on using Desktop and Mobile Extension SDKs in a Universal Windows app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2887e169-348d-4d97-a359-aee413b5fa26/)

Edited 06 oct 2015 - It seems that the issue has been fixed by SDK 1.1.

[What's new for .NET and UWP in Win10 Tools 1.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/09/28/what-s-new-for-net-and-uwp-in-win10-tools-1-1.aspx)